# Logical issue with MVVM (Cross). Take picture after my countdown

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

I have a little problem with my MVVM logic (I use MVVM Cross for Xamarin)

This is my architecture :
[image: MVVM Archi]

I don't know how i can call my Camera.TakePicture in my view (MyViewCamera) ->

In fact, when i click on my button in my view, it is binded on my property StartTimer in MyViewModel, this ViewModel call a function LaunchTimer which call my service TimerCustom().
When my timer (countdown) will be at 0, i want to call my function in my ViewCamera to take picture.

My problem is purely logical. It's MVVM...

Thank you for your help

EDIT my code :

```
 public class TimerCustom
{
    private bool _started; 

    public int Time { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler<int> TimeElapsed;

    public TimerCustom(int startTime)
    {
        Time = startTime + 1; 
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (_started) return;

        _started = true;

        while (_started && Time > 0)
        {
            // wait 1000 ms
            await Task.Delay(1000, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (--Time == 0)
            {
                //Timer finished
                _started = false; 
            }
            TimeElapsed?.Invoke(this, Time);
        }
    }
}
```

My viewmodel :

```
public class SecondStep_Photo_ViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public event TakePictureEvent TakePicture;
    public delegate void TakePictureEvent();

    #region Prop => Display Timer
    private IMvxCommand _displayTimer;

    public IMvxCommand DisplayTimer
    {
        get
        {
            _displayTimer = _displayTimer ?? new MvxCommand(StartTimer);
            return _displayTimer;
        }
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        var timer = new TimerCustom(5);
        timer.TimeElapsed += (s, t) => ValueOfTimer = t;    
        timer.StartAsync(); 
    }
    #endregion
....
```

And in my view i have :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
...

     (base.ViewModel as SecondStep_Photo_ViewModel).TakePicture += SecondStep_Photo_View_TakePicture;

 }

 private void SecondStep_Photo_View_TakePicture()
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Delegate Event` to register the `TakePicture` method and use it within your ViewModel.

```
    public event TakePictureEvent TakePicture;
    public delegate void TakePictureEvent ();
```

Within your `View` you register the event

```
ViewModel.TakePicture += MyTakePictureMethod;
```

After this set the logic for the timer in an `ICommand`

```
private MvxCommand _startTakePictureSequence;
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand StartTakePictureSequence
{
    get
    {
        _startTakePictureSequence = _startTakePictureSequence ?? new MvxCommand(doStartTakePictureSequence);
        return _startTakePictureSequence;
    }
}

private void doStartTakePictureSequence () {

    // You're TimerService call for example
}
```

Now bind the ICommand to a button.

```
 <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TakePictureButton"
        local:MvxBind="ItemClick StartTakePictureSequence" />
```

After the button is selected the seqeunce (doStartTakePictureSequence) starts. The timer service does a countdown and when it reaches 0 you call the delegate `TakePictureEvent()` that takes the picture from the designated device.

This is one way to achieve what you're trying, i'm not sure if this is the way but it is what im using on some of my apps to achieve multiplatform solutions. Where iOS, Android and Windows phone use the same ViewModel.

**Edit**

Adding an `Action` to the `timer.StartAsync` method that calls the `TakePicture delegate`

```
public async Task StartAsync(Action completeAction, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    ...
    completeAction.Invoke();
}
```

And your StartTimer:

```
private void StartTimer()
{
    var timer = new TimerCustom(5);
    timer.TimeElapsed += (s, t) => ValueOfTimer = t;    
    timer.StartAsync(() => {
        TakePicture();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank for your answer, but i have a problem when i want to call my delegate. I can't call my delegate with TakePictureEvent() in my TimerCustom.cs when my timer is over

Comment: You could pass the delegate to the TimerCustom class but I don't know if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Mvvmcross has a plugin called PictureChooser. You should add the nuget package for your core project and android project.

Then the implementation in the core project is something like this;

```
var pictureChooserTask = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPictureChooserTask> ();

pictureChooserTask.TakePicture (maxPixelDimension, quality, stream => {
            if (stream != null) {
                ImageFromCamera = ReadFully (stream);
            }
        }, () => {
        });
```

The picture that is taken is returned as a byte array (ImageFromCamera property).
Bind this to the item click event for a button etc. and it should work smoothly.

Comment: Keep in mind that the usage of Constructor Injection is superior to Mvx.Resolve<> (Dependency Inversion Principle).